# Como actualizar una tabla al eliminar un dato en DJANGO

Tags: python, django

estoy trabajando con Django. Estoy realizando una cesta de la compra con Vistas Basadas en Clases. Todo funciona correctamente, pero quiero que al eliminar un elemento de la cesta (DeleteView) se ejecute una funcion para modificar la cantidad de otra tabla. Solo necesito saber como ejecutar una funcion al confirmar el borrado de un elemento.

```
class CestaDeleteView(generic.DeleteView):
         model = Cesta
         success_url = reverse_lazy('cestas:cesta_list_view')

         @method_decorator(login_required)
         def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
             return super(CestaDeleteView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Hay varias formas, podrías sobreescribir un método de la clase y actualizar antes de borrar dentro de un bloque de transacción en caso que uses postgres, o una vez confirmado que se elimina, hacer algo, y lo otro que puedes hacer es usar signals, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/signals/

Comment: Si, estoy utilizando postgres. Que metodo podria sobreescribir? Tendria que actualizar la tabla una vez confirmado el borrado del elemento de la cesta.

Comment: Ya lo he conseguido!! con post_delete, una de las signals de django. Es muy sencillo. Muchas gracias German

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a la respuesta de German, he conseguido hacer lo que queria. Se hace con signals (señales), Django tiene de varios tipos (antes y despues de guardar, antes y despues de borrar, antes y despues de migrar...)

En el modelo

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver

''' A continuacion de la clase '''

@receiver(models.signals.post_delete, sender=Cesta)
def post_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.pedido.quantity += instance.quantity
    instance.pedido.save()
```